# Mockito test REST method with arguments

Tags: java, rest, mockito

So, I'm trying to test my POST REST METHOD which takes in an argument with Mokcito:

```
@Test
public testRestAdd(){
RESTResource mockResource = Mockito.mock(RESTResource.class);
    String goodInput = "good input";
    Response mockOutput = null; //just for testing
    Mockito.when(RESTResource.addCustomer(Customer.class)).thenReturn(mockOutput);
}
```

And the REST Call is:

```
@POST
@Path("Add")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response addCustomer(final Customer CustomerTemp) throws Throwable {
//Code to add Customer
}
```

I get an error on the Mockito.when line where I'm prompted with a wrong input for addCustomer. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: show more of the addCustomer class.  How is "addCustomer" called?

Comment: Show us the error in full. You seem to be calling the method statically.

Comment: Are you sure you imported the correct `Resource` on your test class? Verify the import statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
Mockito.when(RESTResource.addCustomer(Customer.class)).thenReturn(mockOutput);
```

You call addCustomer passing Customer class, while addCustomer method should receive a Customer object. If you want to return the mock for all Cusotmer instances use Mockito's [isA Matcher](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Matchers.html#isA%28java.lang.Class%29) like this:

```
Mockito.when(RESTResource.addCustomer(org.mockito.Matchers.isA(Customer.class))).thenReturn(mockOutput);
```

Or if you don't really care of which Customer you receive in addCustomer you can use:

```
Mockito.when(RESTResource.addCustomer(org.mockito.Matchers.any())).thenReturn(mockOutput);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on a huge piece of code hence unable to post any part of it. when i tried your solution, it still shows me an error and says expression expected  near Cutomer in isA. Meanwhile, I'm working on posting just tidbits of what my addCustomer does.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I had a misplaced parentheses.

Comment: I tried this: Mockito.when(RESTResource.addCustomer(new Customer())).thenReturn(mockOutput);

Comment: No, because Mockito will return null (or whatever you configure to return) only when addCustomer receives that object you have just created. But because you have created it inlined you don't have a reference to it. You can do this: Customer customer = new Customer(); Mockito.when(RESTResource.addCustomer(customer)).thenReturn(mockOutput);

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Though I was looking only to make it input a customer Object. Thanks for your patience.